# SQLite: Indexes deepness

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have one question about indexes.  As you see below, first Index hast just 2 columns and second one three. My question is, if the second index already covers the first one, because there the same columns at the beginn? Any ideas?

```
CREATE INDEX ix_repl_lexem_scope_2_nr_3 ON replications (contextL1,normalized_word);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX ix_repl_lexem_scope_2_nr_3 ON replications (contextL1,normalized_word,contextR1);
```

Thx u advance=)

Comment: Yes. Your second index makes the first one redundant. Any query that would use the first one can use the second one instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first index is not needed, if you have the second index.

It is important both that the columns be the same *and that they be in the same order*.  The columns in the first index are the same as the initial columns in the second index, so the first is not necessary.

Further, it is not really desirable.  Each index incurs overhead (both space and time) when data changes.  So, you should just stick with the second index.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
And you may use the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` command to check the use of your index.

```
sqlite> CREATE INDEX i2 ON t1(a, b);
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT a, b FROM t1 WHERE a=1; 
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX i2 (a=?)
```

see https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html